# what support does wkhtmltoimage have for colour profiles

Tags: colors, webkit, wkhtmltopdf, color-profile, wkhtmltoimage

On a page converted to an image with wkhtmltoimage:

1. If images on the page contain colour profiles (sRGB, for example), will the profiles be taken into account in the rendered image?
2. If images on the page contain multiple embedded colour profiles (sRGB and Adobe RGB, e.g.) which one (if any) is used?